# Are fields flat $\mathbb Z$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is probably one of those questions with a super obvious counterexample, but here goes.

Is a field necessarily a flat $\mathbb Z$-module?

Comment: Multiplication with 2 is injective $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$. What happens if you $\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb F_2$

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Over a PID (such as $\mathbb{Z}$) being flat is equivalent to being torsion-free. Therefore, if your field is torsion-free, it is flat, and if it has torsion, it is not flat.

Answer (score 12):

A $\mathbb{Z}$-module is flat if and only if it is torsion free, so it might depend on the characteristic of the field.